# Who built the Warp Room in Crash Bandicoot 2?

Tags: video-games, crash-bandicoot

At the beginning of the game, Crash gets teleported from some island ruins to the warp room that serves as the hub of the game. The first room seems to be made of carved stone and looks like the ruins that are found elsewhere on the island, but later rooms look like ice, sewer pipes, a mine, a space station, and

> a castle(?) in the case of the secret warp room.

Has Naughty Dog or any licensed source (strategy guides, etc.) ever established whether it was Cortex or the islanders who built the warp room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this from the *Crash 2* manual (emphasis mine):

> On his way home to get her power pack, Crash is suddenly blinded by a flash of light. Next thing he knows, a holographic projection of Cortex is talking to him in **an ancient Warp Room**!
>
> Cortex tells him about the impending disaster, and urges Crash to help him find the 25 crystals needed to power the only means of survival the Earth has left - the new Cortex Vortex. **He explains that an ancient civilization built the Warp Rooms centuries ago**, and that their door provide instant access to points all over the world - places hiding the coveted crystals! Of course, Cortex doesn't know that the Earth also contains valuable gems - 42 clear and 5 colored - which may hold the key to his downfall!

I don't think this actually gets explained in-game (it's not exactly dialogue-heavy), and I'm not sure how it lines up with the Space room, but it seems like the best answer we have.